# Running Hadoop On Windows 7

Tags: hadoop, windows-7-x64

I'm having trouble running Hadoop 1.0.3 on Windows 7 64-bit.

I'm following directions from [this link](http://blog.sqltrainer.com/2012/01/installing-and-configuring-apache.html).  I've downloaded Cygwin and successfully started the SSH daemon.  I unpacked Hadoop into the Cygwin `/usr/local` folder using Win-Zip 16.5.  I edited the hadoop-env.sh to point to my JDK using [MetaPad](http://liquidninja.com/metapad/):

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02"
```

I ran dos2unix to make sure that I didn't have any issues with characters.

But when I run the hadoop command in Cygwin terminal to get the version I see this:

```
$ bin/hadoop version
bin/hadoop: line 2: $'\r': command not found
bin/hadoop: line 17: $'\r': command not found
bin/hadoop: line 18: $'\r': command not found
bin/hadoop: line 49: $'\r': command not found
: No such file or directoryn
bin/hadoop: line 52: $'\r': command not found
bin/hadoop: line 60: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'in/hadoop: line 60: `case "`uname`" in

Michael@Michael-PC /usr/local/hadoop
$
```

Has anyone seen this?  Is there an easy correction that I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like carriage return difference between unix and windows is causing the problem . 
Try running dos2unix on the shell script

Go to the hadoop bin directory and try :

```
dos2unix.exe hadoop.sh
```

And then try the hadoop command .

Comment: Did that and said so in the original post: "I ran dos2unix to make sure that I didn't have any issues with characters."  But thanks for the thought.

Comment: Double checked and found out that I had successfully transformed all the .sh files.  Too bad the hadoop file wasn't of type .sh.  Once a hex editor showed me that my assumption was wrong I was on my way.  You were correct - thank you.