# Hadoop installation with Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, hadoop

I am installing **cygwin** successfully but when i running **hadoop1.1.1** and type command for find hadoop version error arise

[image]

Note :
1) install java in **C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_43** and runtime environment **C:\Java\jre1.6.0_43**.
2) Also set environment variable

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331944/running-hadoop-on-windows-7

Comment: yes. I am changing my file hadoop-env.sh using(dos2unix.exe hadoop-env.sh) and its working....Thank you